# joining RE requests in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a page.htm file:

```
</td></tr>

  <tr>
    <td height="120" class="box_pic">
    <a href="view.php?item=1322679" target="_blank"><img src="http://s.fdert.com/pics.php?q=4iGjVtivCiBKELV%2BVUi27TIgo9KhXusVoizsXDI8FN1HTLACXmZddfsdsgsdghqJXZkz5vSkYq6xISbd2zaUA%3D%3D" alt="[без описания]" width="140" height="105"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr align="center" valign="middle"> 
    <td valign="top"> 
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
          <td class="box_prc"><span class="nwr"><img src="/map/gender_pair.gif" width="11" height="11" alt="Сова" border=0>&nbsp;<a class="usernick" href="/index.php?action=user&id=79159" target="_blank">ABird</a></span></td>

</td></tr>

  <tr>
    <td height="120" class="box_pic">
    <a href="view.php?item=1546679" target="_blank"><img src="http://s.fdert.com/pics.php?q=4iGjVtivCiBKELV%2BVUi27TIgo9KhXusVoizsXDI8FN1HTLACXmZddfsdsgsdghqJXZkz5vSkYq6xISbd2zaUA%3D%3D" alt="[без описания]" width="140" height="105"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr align="center" valign="middle"> 
    <td valign="top"> 
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
          <td class="box_prc"><span class="nwr"><img src="/map/gender_pair.gif" width="11" height="11" alt="Сова" border=0>&nbsp;<a class="usernick" href="/index.php?action=user&id=78759" target="_blank">ADog</a></span></td>

</td></tr>

  <tr>
    <td height="120" class="box_pic">
    <a href="view.php?item=5622679" target="_blank"><img src="http://s.fdert.com/pics.php?q=4iGjVtivCiBKELV%2BVUi27TIgo9KhXusVoizsXDI8FN1HTLACXmZddfsdsgsdghqJXfdgfdgZkz5vSkYq6xISbd2zaUA%3D%3D" alt="[без описания]" width="140" height="105"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr align="center" valign="middle"> 
    <td valign="top"> 
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
          <td class="box_prc"><span class="nwr"><img src="/map/gender_pair.gif" width="11" height="11" alt="Сова" border=0>&nbsp;<a class="usernick" href="/index.php?action=user&id=87159" target="_blank">ACat56</a></span></td>
```

It has 3 sets of data which I need:

```
1) 1322679 79159 ABird
2) 1546679 78759 ADog
3) 5622679 87159 ACat56
```

I have 3 requests for RE which can dig elements from this page:

```
import re

with open('page.htm', 'r') as our_file:
    page=our_file.read()
result = re.findall(r'view\.php\?item=(\d+)', page)
result2 = re.findall(r'user&id=(\d+)', page)
result3 = re.findall(r'user&id=.*>(\w+)', page)
print (result, len(result))
print (result2, len(result2))
print (result3, len(result3))
```

the result I get:

```
['1322679', '1546679', '5622679'] 3
['79159', '78759', '87159'] 3
['ABird', 'ADog', 'ACat56'] 3
```

Do you know the way to join these 3 requests in ONE? So that

```
1) file would be analized 1 time instead of 3 times
2) only ONE re.findall() would be used
3) data would be joined in the way I need  

  a) 1322679 79159 ABird
    b) 1546679 78759 ADog
    c) 5622679 87159 ACat56
```

the result request should be something like this:

```
result = re.findall(r'view\.php\?item=(\d+) SOMETHING_HERE user&id=(\d+) SOMETHING_HERE .*>(\w+)', page)
```

Comment: One uses the pipe (`|`) as an "or".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, it does not work. I get this with your hint: [('1322679', '', ''), ('', '79159', ''), ('1546679', '', ''), ('', '78759', ''),
 ('5622679', '', ''), ('', '87159', '')] 6

Comment: Google "regex html" and then use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @AlexHall OK. I googled it. They say it is difficult, because of ',", and \. But I'm not trying to get urls here. I'm trying to get simple things. And my separate requests work. I need only the way to join them into one.

Comment: Yeah but did you read the part where the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ?

Comment: What alex is trying to say is, regular expressions are not how you should parse html, even if you get something to work it will be hacky and fragile to change. There are much better tools available, such as beautiful soup, and you should use them instead.

Comment: @AlexHall forget about htm, consider it to be strange txt file. I only need to put something instead of SOMETHING_HERE which would mean any number of any symbols up to the nearest next "user&id=(\d+)"

Comment: @AlexHall are you still so sure that it's not possible to do with regex only? Without BS. See the new answer.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but it's very hard to do it well. Your approach is hard to understand and the part with `.{,700}` is particularly strange and risky. If you or someone else has to modify the code months from now you're going to have a hard time understanding it and likely break it.

Comment: @AlexHall You are right. I found a way to say to RE - "find the nearest next pattern" - it is .*? instead of .{,700} or .{,25}. Now the answer is perfect. Your answer is good, but it is too big, uses external module and not exactly what I asked. But again, thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally, I found the solution:

This is the answer, which satisfies all the requirements:

```
import re

with open('page.htm', 'r') as our_file:
    page=our_file.read()

page = re.sub(r'[\t\r\n\s]','',page)

re.DOTALL
result = re.findall(r'view\.php\?item=(\d+).*?user&id=(\d+).*?>(\w+)', page)

print (result, len(result))
```

and:

```
1) results are in needed order
2) 1 request
```

result:

```
[('1322679', '79159', 'ABird'), ('1546679', '78759', 'ADog'), ('5622679', '87159', 'ACat56')] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it properly with an HTML parser in Python 2:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs, urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def only(x):
    x = list(x)
    assert len(x) == 1
    return x[0]

def url_params(a):
    return parse_qs(urlparse(a['href']).query)

def main():
    with open('page.html') as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    rows = soup.find_all('tr', recursive=False)

    # Data is in alternating rows, so take pairs of rows at a time
    for row1, row2 in zip(rows[::2], rows[1::2]):
        a = only(row1.select('td.box_pic a'))
        item_id = only(url_params(a)['item'])
        a = only(row2.select('a.usernick'))
        user_id = only(url_params(a)['id'])
        nick = a.text
        print item_id, user_id, nick

main()
```

Output:

```
1322679 79159 ABird
1546679 78759 ADog
5622679 87159 ACat56
```

Now, this may not be as concise as the re method, but this code is aware of how the input is meant to be structured and that makes it robust. If the structure of the input changes, e.g. the format of the URLs or the shape of the HTML, this code will either continue to work correctly or it will raise an error to tell you that things aren't as expected. The re method may very easily continue to run but give you incorrect results, which is not a situation you want. And if you want to extract more information in the future, it's very easy to add the necessary lines without interfering with the existing code.

Comment: from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse and print () - it is for python3. But anyway, I'll try to understand how it works. Thank you for your attention and time.